# Daypilot with MVC3 Assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, daypilot

I have been trying to add daypilot to my project.

I have added all the code I thought I needed but this error I'm getting is confusing me. 
I'm guessing i have a incompatible version of daypilot??

My error is displayed in this photo.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/mvc3r.png/

Comment: your daypilot is depend on MVC4. You need to have mvc4 referenced in your project.If you have MVC3 then include version MVC version 4dll to compile your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using MVC 3.0 in your project while DayPilot uses MVC 4.0.
Change your usage of MVC package to 4.0

Comment: <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Does this not mean i am using MVC3??

Comment: Seems I read your error message a bit too fast and got it backwards. You are using MVC 3 and DayPilot is using MVC 4. I updated the answer accordingly